# Grouping SQL rows into a transaction then calculating duration

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that's structured like the one below.  I'm wondering if it's possible to compress each transaction by the TransactionID, pull values from the first and last row, then finally calculate a duration for the transaction.

For instance below, I would like to pull RecordID and CustomerID.  Then alias a new column called startingStatus which would be 'Submitted' from the first row.  I would alias a second column called endingStatus that would be 'Success' from the last row. I then need to grab the timestamps in the same manner, creating startingTime and endingTime.  The final column would be the difference between starting and ending in seconds.

```
RecordID    TransactionID   CustomerID  Status          TimeStamp
1                   12          10      Submitted       04/07/2014 14:32:23
2                   12          10      Queued          04/07/2014 14:32:24
3                   12          10      Processing      04/08/2014 14:32:26
4                   12          10      Error           04/09/2014 14:32:27
5                   12          10      Resubmitted     04/10/2014 15:12:29
6                   12          10      Queued          04/11/2014 15:12:31
7                   12          10      Processing      04/12/2014 15:12:34
8                   12          10      Success         04/13/2014 15:12:47
```

I've been trying to group by TransactionID and using MIN and MAX, but I haven't gotten it working yet.

How would I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
    CustomerID, 
    TransactionID, 
    Min([TimeStamp]) as StartTime, 
    Max([TimeStamp]) as EndTime,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Min([TimeStamp]),Max([TimeStamp])) as TransactionTime
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CustomerID, TransactionID
ORDER BY CustomerID, TransactionID
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use window functions to retrieve the first and last records for a group.

This will work for SQL Server 2005 and later by using the ROW_NUMBER() window function and then pivoting the results with the MAX/CASE WHEN method:

```
SELECT 
    [TransactionID], 
    [CustomerID], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN [rn_asc] = 1 THEN [Status] ELSE NULL END) [startingStatus], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN [rn_desc] = 1 THEN [Status] ELSE NULL END) [endingStatus], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN [rn_asc] = 1 THEN [TimeStamp] ELSE NULL END) [startingTimeStamp], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN [rn_desc] = 1 THEN [TimeStamp] ELSE NULL END) [endingTimeStamp],
    DATEDIFF(
        SECOND,
        MAX(CASE WHEN [rn_asc] = 1 THEN [TimeStamp] ELSE NULL END),
        MAX(CASE WHEN [rn_desc] = 1 THEN [TimeStamp] ELSE NULL END) 
    ) [duration]
FROM  
    ( 
        SELECT 
            [TransactionID], 
            [CustomerID], 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [TransactionID], [CustomerID] ORDER BY [RecordID] ASC) [rn_asc], 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [TransactionID], [CustomerID] ORDER BY [RecordID] DESC) [rn_desc], 
            [Status], 
            [Timestamp] 
        FROM [tbl]
    ) A 
GROUP BY  
    [TransactionID], 
    [CustomerID]
```

SQL Server 2012 introduced the FIRST_VALUE function, so if you're running that version you can consider this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [TransactionID], 
    [CustomerID], 
    FIRST_VALUE([Status]) OVER (PARTITION BY [TransactionID], [CustomerID] ORDER BY [RecordID] ASC) [startingStatus], 
    FIRST_VALUE([Status]) OVER (PARTITION BY [TransactionID], [CustomerID] ORDER BY [RecordID] DESC) [endingStatus],
    FIRST_VALUE([TimeStamp]) OVER (PARTITION BY [TransactionID], [CustomerID] ORDER BY [RecordID] ASC) [startingTimeStamp], 
    FIRST_VALUE([TimeStamp]) OVER (PARTITION BY [TransactionID], [CustomerID] ORDER BY [RecordID] DESC) [endingTimeStamp],
    DATEDIFF(
        SECOND,
        FIRST_VALUE([TimeStamp]) OVER (PARTITION BY [TransactionID], [CustomerID] ORDER BY [RecordID] ASC),
        FIRST_VALUE([TimeStamp]) OVER (PARTITION BY [TransactionID], [CustomerID] ORDER BY [RecordID] DESC)
    ) [duration]
FROM [tbl]
```